# Отправка писем на почту вызовом mail

Tags: email, php, sendmail

Приветствую Всех!

Возникла проблема, пытаюсь отправить письмо со вложением на почту с localhost (win7, apache) пишет, что отправлено (выдает true), а на почте писем нет, проверял и на почту mail.ru и на gmail.com - один и тот же результат.

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
function mail_attach($to, $from, $subj, $text, $files = null, $isHTML = false)
{
    $boundary = "------------" . strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand())));
    $headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n
                  X-Mailer: koz1024.net\r\n
                  MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
                  Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n\r\n
                 ";
    if (!$isHTML) {
        $type = 'text/plain';
    } else {
        $type = 'text/html';
    }
    $body = $boundary . "\r\n\r\n
                Content-Type:" . $type . "; charset=utf-8\r\n
                Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n
                " . $text . "\r\n\r\n";
    if ((is_array($files)) && (!empty($files))) {
        foreach ($files as $filename => $filecontent) {
            $body .= $boundary . "\r\n
                    Content-Type: application/octet-stream;name=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n
                    Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n
                    Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n\r\n
                    " . chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontent));
        }
    }
    return mail($to, $subj, $body, $headers);
}

$files = array(
    'archive.zip' => file_get_contents('files/archive.zip')
);
if (mail_attach('vitalik.tjuryakin@gmail.com', 'attach@text.com', 'Test 1', 'Hello attach...', $files, false)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
?>
```

Вставлял в начале: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - так же, ошибок не обнаружено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне возможно, что отправка писем эмулируется - письма не отправляются, а сохраняются в определенной папке. К примеру, в Денвере под Windows отправленные письма падают в \WebServers\tmp\!sendmail

Comment: В папке там они хранятся, только как сделать так, чтобы все таки уходило, т.к. это будет производиться с LocalHost.

Comment: [Попробуйте поменять настройки PHP](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html)